# Vertically align block-level element in a list item within a nested list using counters?

Tags: html, css

I have a nested list with counters:

```
1   Foo
1.1 Foo Foo
2   Bar
2.1 Bar Bar
```

Now I have multiline text in my subitems but do not want them to flow around the counter like they normally do.

```
1.1 Lorem
Ipsum
```

Instead, I want the whole text to be horizontally aligned.

```
1.1 Lorem
    Ipsum
```

So my next idea was to include a paragraph (or any kind of block-level element for that matter) within the list item so the text will be neatly aligned.

```
1.1
Lorem
Ipsum
```

But this introduces another problem as the text does not start on the line of the counter anymore.

So my genius idea was to just give the p-tag some relative repositioning so it appears where I want it.

```css
/* Counter */

ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: list-item-number;
}

li {
  counter-increment: list-item-number;
}

li::before {
  content: counters(list-item-number, ".") " ";
}


/* Align the P */

ol li ol li p {
  position: relative;
  top: -2em; /* THIS NEVER PROPERLY ALIGNS! */
  left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum
    <ol>
      <li>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. At
          volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis.
          Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Interdum posuere
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
        </p>
        <p>
          Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum. Volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
          scelerisque eleifend donec. In ornare quam viverra orci. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Volutpat diam ut venenatis
          tellus in metus vulputate. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Erat velit scelerisque in dictum non. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper
          morbi. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat. Quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea.
        </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

But if you try this you'll notice that the top is never properly vertically aligned with the text. Even when I'm trying to be pixel-perfect I'm always off by one or two pixels. Why is that? Does anybody have any idea that might help me out? Or maybe my whole approach is utterly stupid - in that case, please tell me as well. :)

Also - I can only use CSS2 as this is going into a 3rd-party PDF renderer (Salesforce, to be specific) that has been really updated for the last 12 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider CSS grid and a two column layout:

```css
/* Counter */

ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: list-item-number;
}

li {
  counter-increment: list-item-number;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto 1fr;
  grid-column-gap:5px
}

li::before {
  content: counters(list-item-number, ".") " ";
  /*grid-column:1 no need to specify it since it's by default */
}

li * {
  grid-column:2; /* everything on the second column */
}

p {
  margin-top:0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum
    <ol>
      <li>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. At
          volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis.
          Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Interdum posuere
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
        </p>
        <p>
          Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum. Volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
          scelerisque eleifend donec. In ornare quam viverra orci. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Volutpat diam ut venenatis
          tellus in metus vulputate. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Erat velit scelerisque in dictum non. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper
          morbi. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat. Quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea.
        </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. At
          volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis.
          Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Interdum posuere
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
        </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum
    <ol>
      <li>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. At
          volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis.
          Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Interdum posuere
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
        </p>
        <p>
          Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum. Volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
          scelerisque eleifend donec. In ornare quam viverra orci. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Volutpat diam ut venenatis
          tellus in metus vulputate. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Erat velit scelerisque in dictum non. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper
          morbi. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat. Quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea.
        </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. At
          volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis.
          Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Interdum posuere
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
        </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Or a table layout:

```css
/* Counter */

ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: list-item-number;
}

li {
  counter-increment: list-item-number;
  display:table-row;
}

li::before {
  content: counters(list-item-number, ".") " ";
  display:table-cell;
  white-space:nowrap;
  padding-right:5px;
}

p {
  margin-top:0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum
    <ol>
      <li>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. At
          volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis.
          Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Interdum posuere
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
        </p>
        <p>
          Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum. Volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
          scelerisque eleifend donec. In ornare quam viverra orci. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Volutpat diam ut venenatis
          tellus in metus vulputate. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Erat velit scelerisque in dictum non. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper
          morbi. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat. Quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea.
        </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. At
          volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis.
          Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Interdum posuere
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
        </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum
    <ol>
      <li>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. At
          volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis.
          Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Interdum posuere
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
        </p>
        <p>
          Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum. Volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
          scelerisque eleifend donec. In ornare quam viverra orci. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Volutpat diam ut venenatis
          tellus in metus vulputate. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Erat velit scelerisque in dictum non. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper
          morbi. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat. Quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea.
        </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. At
          volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis.
          Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Interdum posuere
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
        </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

The content will adjust automatically in case you change the counter:

```css
/* Counter */

ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: list-item-number 100;
}

li {
  counter-increment: list-item-number;
  display:table-row;
}

li::before {
  content: counters(list-item-number, ".") " __ ";
  display:table-cell;
  white-space:nowrap;
  padding-right:5px;
}

p {
  margin-top:0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum
    <ol>
      <li>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. At
          volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis.
          Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Interdum posuere
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
        </p>
        <p>
          Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum. Volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
          scelerisque eleifend donec. In ornare quam viverra orci. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Volutpat diam ut venenatis
          tellus in metus vulputate. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Erat velit scelerisque in dictum non. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper
          morbi. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat. Quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea.
        </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. At
          volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis.
          Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Interdum posuere
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
        </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum
    <ol>
      <li>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. At
          volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis.
          Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Interdum posuere
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
        </p>
        <p>
          Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum. Volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
          scelerisque eleifend donec. In ornare quam viverra orci. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Volutpat diam ut venenatis
          tellus in metus vulputate. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Erat velit scelerisque in dictum non. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper
          morbi. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat. Quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea.
        </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. At
          volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis.
          Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Interdum posuere
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
        </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: While this works great I need something that works in my old-school renderer. So no CSS3. Sorry - I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @Semmel check the update, you won't find older that table layout (worth to note that both solutions works with any kind of content, even big numerotation)

Comment: I like the solution with the table layout as it seems the most straightforward. I will test it and see how it works after rendering.

Comment: @Semmel I also advise you to reconsider you PDF rendrer. A 12 years old one is not a good idea. You will have a lot of headaches ;)

Comment: I agree. The problem is that I cannot choose what is being used. And Salesforce does not care about these things very much as I have plenty of issues caused by ~10-year-old bugs not being fixed.

Comment: So the table-layout seems the only solution that works consistently and does not cause other weird 1-pixel bugs. It also the easiest to understand and very compatible so I'll go with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: absolute` in `::before`

```css
/* Counter */

ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: list-item-number;
}

li {
  counter-increment: list-item-number;
  position: relative
}

li::before {
  content: counters(list-item-number, ".") " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: -2em;
  top: 0;
  /* to keep the same distance from counter to text */
  text-align: right;
  /*whatever you prefer here */
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum
    <ol>
      <li>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. At
          volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis.
          Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Interdum posuere
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.
        </p>
        <p>
          Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec. Auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum. Volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
          scelerisque eleifend donec. In ornare quam viverra orci. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Volutpat diam ut venenatis
          tellus in metus vulputate. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Erat velit scelerisque in dictum non. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper
          morbi. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat. Quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea.
        </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick but I do not understand why or rather how this works. I need to do some more testing.

Comment: For some reason, this only works in the HTML but has a different 1-pixel bug in the Salesforce PDF renderer. More specifically it is aligned with the counter on the bottom but seems to be off by 1 pixel on the top (it is missing). This could also be caused by me or my CSS but it's hard to say for sure as the PDF renderer has many issues I need to work around.